# Сравнение двух JSONArray массивов

Tags: java, android, алгоритм

Добрый день.

Есть приложение, которое получает 2 массива `JSONArray` с объектами, в которых находится по 3 поля. У каждого объекта есть поле_id `int` с каким-то значением. Размеры каждого массива всегда разные. Один массив может быть равен 300, другой 3000. Необходимо их сравнить и найти объекты, значения полей поле_id одинаковые.

Подскажите как правильно это реализовать?

Первое, что приходит в голову, это сделать 2 цикла, в которых объекты каждого массива помещаются в 2 разных `ArrayList<JSONObject>`, а потом в цикле каждое значение большего списка сравнивать со всеми значениями меньшего списка, но что-то мне подсказывает, что это неправильное решение, которое займёт очень много времени.

Может есть какие-то более правильные решения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один массив кладёте в Map-у, с ключами id.

А второй просто в цикле прогоняете, беря из Map-ы объект с ключом из второго массива. Зная что по Map-е поиск идёт за константное время, сложность алгоритма получается в O(N).

Никаких собственных сложных алгоритмов реализовывать не придётся, просто цикл.

---

Код примерно такой:

```
JSONArray one = ...
JSONArray two = ...

Map<Integer, JSONObject> idsToOneElements = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < one.length; ++i) {
    JSONObject object = one.getJSONObject(i);
    idsToOneElements.put(object.getInt("id"), object);
}

List<JSONObject> commonElements = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < two.length; ++i) {
    JSONObject object = two.getJSONObject(i);
    if (idsToOneElements.containsKey(object.getInt("id"))) {
        commonElements.add(object);
    }
}
```

(Используются классы [`JSONArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html), [`JSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html), [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) и методы [`JSONArray.length`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#length()), [`JSONArray.getJSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#getJSONObject(int)), [`JSONObject.getInt`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getInt(java.lang.String)), [`HashMap.put`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-), [`HashMap.containsKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-). Вместо `HashMap<Integer, JSONObject>` можно был в принципе и [`HashSet<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) использовать)

Comment: может код добавить

Comment: @diraria увы не могу, я программирую на C#, а на Java уже больше 12 лет как не пишу. На C# это для меня пару минут такой алгоритм написать, на Java разбираться придётся с названиеми функций которые я не знаю.

Comment: добавил код, если не понравится можно удалить

Comment: @diraria Большое спасибо! Тут нету возможности репутацией отблагодарить вас, но думаю что знаю способ!

Answer (score 2):

Идея такова: отсортировать quick sort-ом массив по этим самым id, а затем для каждого такого массива выполнить бинарный поиск. Это самые быстрые алгоритмы, которые избавят вас от необходимости перебирать каждый элемент и сравнивать со всеми другими.
В Java уже есть метод для быстрой сортировки, а бинарный поиск или уже есть, или вы можете написать сами.